# VB .NET JSON Deserialization

Tags: json, vb.net

I'm having a problem with JSON deserialization hope you can help me.
I have a JSON that have the following information:

```
{  
"object":"list",
"more":false,
"data":[  
  {  
     "object":"number",
     "id":"1",
     "code":"1",
     "name":"One",
  },
  {  
     "object":"number",
     "id":"2",
     "code":"2",
     "name":"Two",
  }
  ...
```

So I've a created a simple app so I can use that information:

```
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim uriString As String = "API URL"
    Dim uri As New Uri(uriString)

    'Make Request
    Dim Request As HttpWebRequest = HttpWebRequest.Create(uri)
    Request.Method = "GET"

    'Get Response
    Dim Response As HttpWebResponse = Request.GetResponse()

    'Read Response
    Dim Read = New StreamReader(Response.GetResponseStream())
    Dim Raw As String = Read.ReadToEnd()

    'Convert response

    Dim dict As Object = New JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize(Of List(Of Object))(Raw)

    For Each item In dict
        MsgBox(item)
        MsgBox(item("code"))
        TextBox1.Text += item("code").ToString + " - " + item("name").ToString + vbNewLine
    Next
End Sub
```

It seems I get the response, since the Read I get the JSON, but after that, I can't get the information listed in that JSON. What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: "code" is not in first level. You have to enter proper level to get what you want, like  item("data")(1)("code")

Comment: Even if I use item("data")("code") or item("data")(1)("code") it doesnt work. It seems that could be something else.

Comment: Ah yes, I was too quick to respond without looking properly. You are not deserializing properly.  Use JavaScriptSerializer().DeserializeObject(Raw) then TextBox1.Text = item("data")(0)("code") will work.

Comment: Sorry, but what's supposed to be JSON_Obj1? Can't identify it. I'm using Web Script Serialization. That way it seems I cant run all the codes in a for each loop or I'm wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not de-serializing properly. Your dict is empty like that.

This will work as intended.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim uriString As String = "API URL"
    Dim Request As HttpWebRequest = WebRequest.Create(New Uri(uriString))
    Dim JSON_Response As String = New StreamReader(Request.GetResponse().GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd()

    Dim JSON_Obj1 As Object = New JavaScriptSerializer().DeserializeObject(JSON_Response)
    Dim Test1 as String = JSON_Obj1("data")(0)("code")

    For Each item In JSON_Obj1("data")
        Debug.Print(item("code"))
    Next
End Sub
```