# How parse a JQuery datatable result in vb.net

Tags: jquery, vb.net, datatables

ve to interface my application with a search function of an external website.
I managed to to the search using httpclient, and download the result as a string text.
After searching I found out that it could be a JQuery datatable
here an example:

```
{"draw":15,"recordsTotal":3,"recordsFiltered":3,"data":[["value1","value2","value3","value4","value5","value6","value7","value8"],["value1","value2","value3","value4","value5","value6","value7","value8"],["value21","value22","value23","value24","value25","value26","value27","value28"]["value31","value32","value33","value34","value35","value36","value37","value38"]]}
```

Now, to manipulate this records I would convert them into a collection or a list of objects. I've found anything about similar task.
Is there any way to accomplish this goal?
Note that there is not property names in the file, after "data": it's all data values.
I tried to deserialize as this examples:
[VB .NET JSON Deserialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55992738/vb-net-json-deserialization?rq=3)
[VB.net JSON Deserialize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8118019/vb-net-json-deserialize)

but I'm still get exceptions.

Comment: Are you just looking to deserialize JSON in VB?

Comment: I'm sorry I'm not very familiar with web development and JSON. What I hould is convert the string above into a list of object with the values from this datatable as property values. So in this example a list or collection of 3 objects with 8 properties each one.

Comment: Then it sounds like you're simply not familiar with the terminology.  What you have is JSON data, and what you're looking to do is "deserialize" that data (from its string form) into an object structure.  The linked duplicate can help, and with this terminology you can find a variety of examples online to get started.

Comment: I actually tried to deserialize as the answer linked and other founded on S.O. but without success.

Comment: What did you try and what didn't work as expected?  Please update the question to include a [mcve] of the attempt and specific debugging information about the problem observed.